# kds library gives AttributeError: module 'kds' has no attribute 'metrics'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

Hi I am trying to use `pypi kds` package.
I have installed it with: `pip install kds` 

I didn't have any installation problem. But when I ran the following example script:

```
# REPRODUCABLE EXAMPLE
# Load Dataset and train-test split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import tree

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33,random_state=3)
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1,random_state=3)
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_prob = clf.predict_proba(X_test)

# The magic happens here
import kds
kds.metrics.report(y_test, y_prob)
```

It gives an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-fa00bcb248e7> in <module>
     13 # The magic happens here
     14 import kds
---> 15 kds.metrics.report(y_test, y_prob)

AttributeError: module 'kds' has no attribute 'metrics'
```

Comment: Hey can you please mention the version of `kds` module

Comment: version 0.1.2 (the latest)

Comment: Please update the package to 0.1.3

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved in the latest version. Please update the package using `pip install kds`

Also don't forget the **y_prob[:,1]** in the last line. (output of scikit learn has 2 columns, so select 1 column)

```
# The magic happens here
import kds
kds.metrics.plot_lift(y_test, y_prob[:,1])
```